# In AWS Lambda, setting a header attribute with a variable

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda

In my lambda call I get an OAuth token then I need to use that in my web service call.

I tried various approaches including just appending in the header: `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token` and the following approach:

```
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    var id = event.id;
    var access_token = "ddddd-ccccc-eeee-ffff-gggg";
    var access_header = "Bearer ${access_token}";
    var path = '/sample/someservice/1.0/myService/' + id;
    console.log("access header: " + access_header);
    console.log("path: " + path);
    // TODO implement
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            host: 'host.mycompany.com',
            method: 'GET',
            port: 443,
            crossDomain: true,
            path: path,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': data.length,
                'Authorization': access_header
            }
```

Ultimately I want to be able to use the `access_token` variable and set the `Bearer` value properly.

Appending did work in `path` and I could use that in my `options`.

Comment: Did you try to use backtick? replace your access_header quotes to backtick(`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
var access_header = "Bearer ${access_token}";
```

should be written as

```
var access_header = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
```

should have backtick "`" instead of double quote. This is es6 style .